# Find all $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ satisfying $A^3 + 3A = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Find all $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ such that $A^3+3A=I$, where $I$ is the identity.

I already know one matrix satisfying this equation, which is ((0,0,1),(1,0,-3),(0,1,0)), and I want to show that all matrices satisfying the equation are conjugate to this matrix. I know that all matrices satisfying this equation have characteristic polynomial x^3+3x-1 and I guess that this is also the minimal polynomial for all real matrices satisfying it but I am unable to show it. I think that all matrices having same characteristic and minimal polynomials are the same, which I can use to prove the above, but am unable to prove this result too.

Comment: What do you know about the Cayley Hamilton theorem?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted decomposing the polynomial?

Comment: Hi Egbert, welcome to MSE. Our site's standards require that you shows some of your own work/thoughts towards this question, even if they didn't get you anywhere. This allows us to figure out what you need help with, and helps us avoid explaining things you already understand. Please edit your question with some of your thoughts, otherwise your question may be down-voted and closed.

Comment: Please, check the following guidelines: [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). They may help you.

Comment: I already know one matrix satisfying this equation, which is ((0,0,1),(1,0,-3),(0,1,0)),and I want to show that all real matrices satisfying the equation are conjugate to this matrix. I know that all matrices satisfying this equation have characteristic polynomial x^3+3x-1 and I guess that this is also the minimal polynomial for all real matrices satisfying it but I am unable to show it. I think that all matrices having same characteristic and minimal polynomials are the same, which I can use to prove the above, but am unable to prove this result too.

Comment: $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}}$ and $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}}$ have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials, but are clearly not similar.

Comment: But that's 4x4 matrices. I read a result for 3x3 matrices somewhere. I just can't prove that all real matrices satisfying the equation have the same minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3 + 3x - 1$ has three distinct roots: one real, and two conjugate complex roots. If you assume that it is the minimal polynomial for a (let's say) complex matrix $A$, then the three roots of the polynomial must be the three eigenvalues of $A$, each of which are distinct, meaning that $A$ is diagonalisable. That is, $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix containing the roots of $x^3 + 3x - 1 = 0$ in the diagonal. Thus, any two such matrices $A$ and $B$ must be similar to each other, exactly as you want.

Note that I assumed that the polynomial $x^3 + 3x - 1$ is minimal. If we relax this condition, then we will obtain other such matrices. For example, if $\lambda$ is a root of $x^3 + 3x - 1$, then $A = \lambda I$ will be a matrix, not similar to the previous matrices, that will satisfy the given polynomial equation.

Since $x^3 + 3x - 1$ is square-free (i.e. it has distinct roots), we know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be a (square-free) factor of this polynomial, and hence $A$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues taken from the roots of $x^3 + 3x - 1$. You'll have to consider the three roots $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, and all possibility of repeated eigenvalues taken from this list of three roots. These will form the similarity classes of matrices which satisfy this polynomial equation.